# SQL Query to return a value based on data in a range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables - list of customers with a total next to them, they also have a type column and a status record.

For example

```
CustomerName, TotalOR, Type, Status
Customer 1, 205, P, Maint
Customer 2, 199, S, Maint
```

and a second table with the details with the service band in which they fall.

```
Band, Type, Status, TotalORFrom, TotalORTo
B1, P, Maint, 1, 199
B2, P, Maint, 199, 300
B3, S, Maint, 1, 199
```

What I want to be able to do is return the Band for each customer based on the customers TotalOR, Type and Status.

I have tried to create multiple queries which I can get it to return all possible bands, but not the specific band. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first table is `customer` and the second table is `band`:

```
SELECT band
FROM customer c
JOIN band b ON c.Type = b.Type
AND c.Status = b.Status
AND (c.TotalOR = b.TotalORFrom OR c.TotalOR = b.TotalORTo)
```

**Edit:** I can't tell if you're trying to join based on `TotalORFrom` or `TotalORTo`, so this query joins based on either one being the same.

**Edit 2:** Based on your comment, here is a new query that ensures `customer.TotalOR` is-greater-than-or-equal to `band.TotalORFrom` and `customer.TotalOR` is less-than-or-equal-to `band.TotalORTo`.

```
SELECT band
FROM customer c
JOIN band b ON c.Type = b.Type
AND c.Status = b.Status
AND c.TotalOR BETWEEN b.TotalORFrom AND b.TotalORTo
```

---

UPDATE: the above seems to cause an overlap of `B1` and `B2` at `199` for `P, Maint`. Consider this alternative to eliminate the overlap:

```
SELECT band
FROM customer c
JOIN band b ON c.Type = b.Type
AND c.Status = b.Status
AND c.TotalOR >= b.TotalORFrom
AND c.TotalOR < b.TotalORTo;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to join based on if the value falls between the range in TotalORFrom and TotalORTo. For example in my customer table customer 1 would be in band b2 and customer 2 would be in band b3.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct so that others know the question is solved. Thanks.

Comment: To my eye, this would cause an overlap of `B1` and `B2` at `199` for `P, Maint`. See edit to question, was too long for comments alone ;)

Comment: I don't disagree with the overlap, but the OP doesn't specify that overlap is bad. We have no knowledge which of the ends are supposed to inclusive (the TO? The FROM? both? neither?). I assumed they were both inclusive.